# Intellisense for Firebase with VScode

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code

How can I get intellisense to work on VS code?
I have the last VSCODE version, am in windows 10, and I've installed node packages with NPM.  I wonder if there is an extension to install to get Intellisense to work.

For information, I have a jsconfig.json file with the content below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use Firebase extension for vs code. Check out this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=toba.vsfire

Comment: i've already tried this extension it doesn't work

Comment: Can you try to install TypeScript as per this article and check again?https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript

Comment: Thank you, I've tried, it still doesn't work

Comment: If your code loses type information somewhere along the way, TypeScript won't be able to infer the types.  Not much you can do about that but be specific about them in your code. It's hard to tell from what you've shown.  Try starting with a very simple code sample.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I set my firebase.js file

```js
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import firebase from "firebase/app"

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"

// PUT YOUR OWN FIREBASE CONFIGURATION HERE
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
  authDomain: process.env.authDomain,
  projectId: process.env.projectId,
  storageBucket: process.env.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.messagingSenderId,
  appId: process.env.appId,
}
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth()
const firestore = firebase.firestore()

export { firebaseAuth, firestore }
```

`firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` is called globally and initialized the app before I declare my auth and firestore constants. Since initializeApp is called before everything, the intellisense pops up now.

Comment: Perfect. So weird firebase has these odd things to make intellisense work.